# R - change variable format from int to hour

Tags: r, time

I have a column in a data frame where is reported the hour in which an event occurred. Just the hours, not minutes or seconds.
This is formatted as an integer, but I would like to make R read it as an Hour (Time). I've checked the documentation for as.Date but there is nothing which can help me.

I've tried with the following command, but it return an error message:

```
> attach(data)
> Hour <- as.Date(Hour, "%H")
```

but it returns the following error message:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Many thanks,

Gianluca

Comment: What is the difference in your mind between the data as numbers and the data as an `hour` type?  There is no inherent type called `hours` it has to be part of a time that includes the full date...

Comment: Ok, so is there no difference for R when processing it? I was just willing to use the right format. I'm quite a beginner, so I'm not fully aware of the difference it might have. I was just trying to have the most tiny dataset possible.

Comment: The error you've shown is meaningful.  A date cannot exist if you only specify the hour of the day (and in fact, a `Date` has no hours, a `time` has hours (`?POSIXct`).  Treating hours as numbers is probably the best way to go depending on your end goal.

Comment: Perhaps, something like `strptime(as.integer(c(1,5,14)), format = "%H") + 3600` is helpful? (The `+ 3600` part is just to show the `'+.POSIXt'` method, i.e. "R read it as hour").

Answer (score 2):

Date objects are points in time - so are a day and a time of day.

If you want to format an hour as a nice format, use `sprintf`:

```
 sprintf("%02d:00",1:24)
 [1] "01:00" "02:00" "03:00" "04:00" "05:00" "06:00" "07:00" "08:00" "09:00"
[10] "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00" "16:00" "17:00" "18:00"
[19] "19:00" "20:00" "21:00" "22:00" "23:00" "24:00"
```

BUT only do that for when you want pretty output, not for computation.

And here's another idea. Create a class for your hour integers...

```
> h = 1:24
> class(h)="hours"
> h
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
attr(,"class")
[1] "hours"
```

all that's done so far is add the 'class' attribute. Let's write a format method:

```
 format.hours<- function(x,...){sprintf("%02d:00",x)}
 format.hours(h)
 [1] "01:00" "02:00" "03:00" "04:00" "05:00" "06:00" "07:00" "08:00" "09:00"
[10] "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00" "16:00" "17:00" "18:00"
[19] "19:00" "20:00" "21:00" "22:00" "23:00" "24:00"
```

We don't want to have to keep typing `format` so let's hook that into the print function:

```
> print.hours <- function(x,...){print(format(x))}
> h
 [1] "01:00" "02:00" "03:00" "04:00" "05:00" "06:00" "07:00" "08:00" "09:00"
[10] "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00" "16:00" "17:00" "18:00"
[19] "19:00" "20:00" "21:00" "22:00" "23:00" "24:00"
```

Sweet. We can also make data frame columns with our hour class vectors:

```
 df = data.frame(h = as.numeric(h),x=runif(24)) ; class(df$h)="hours"
 df
       h          x
1  01:00 0.74339236
2  02:00 0.61240165
3  03:00 0.65007809
4  04:00 0.24844327
5  05:00 0.80499618
```

That last example can be made to work better if you write some more data frame methods.

You can then go on to write arithmetic methods for hour classes, so that adding hours doesn't go to 24 (its just mod 24 airthmetic), or you can modify this to include minutes, seconds, and package up a whole load of clock-time handling code....

But I've flown well off the handle here....

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you start with the `lubridate` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html), which has a thoughtful array of time-handling functions. You may not end up using them, but the documentation will surely make you THINK about the whole issue, which you will surely find useful.

For example, you can represent Durations explicitly and then use them in conjunction with traditional representations of time, such as the Date or Time classes:

```
> dminutes(3)
[1] "180s (~3 minutes)"
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2013-12-31"
> Sys.Date() - dminutes(3)
[1] "2013-12-30 23:57:00 UTC"
```

The documentation says,

```
"Details

When paired with date-times, these functions allow date-times to be manipulated in a method similar to object oriented programming. Period objects can be added to Date, POSIXct, and POSIXlt objects to calculate new date-times."
```

Comment: Ah, but these are *durations* (eg "it lasted six hours and ten minutes"), not the time-of-day (eg "It happens every ten-past six in the morning")  which is what the OP is working with. I have a feeling there's a package for handling clock times somewhere...